# Ubuntu 16.0.4 Virtual Box fresh Install network not working

Tags: networking, 16.04, virtualbox

I apologize as I am not very skilled in Linux. I created a virtual machine yesterday and the network worked but I realized I didn't create the hard drive large enough so I made a new one. For some reason I am unable to connect to the internet on this one and I have no clue why. I am using the NAT connection within VirtualBox and running sudo lshw -c network gives the response below. I need internet to install package but I have no idea how to fix this. What should I try?

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: enp0s3
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:75:04:57
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.2.15 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f0000000-f001ffff ioport:d010(size=8)
```

Comment: Go to the Network icon in the top panel and make sure that `Enable Networking` and `Enable Wi-Fi` are both checked. You should probably also use `bridged` networking, if you want to be able to access other devices on your local network.

Comment: In the Network Settings screen, how many items are there in the Network Adapter `Name` drop down?  Also, what is the name of the one selected?

Comment: Enable networking is checked, I am connected through a wired connection. There aren't any other devices on the network I am trying to access. L.D. are you asking for adapters on the windows host or linux? I am using a Ethernet cable on the laptop.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my Virtualbox settings or my host computer as there is no internet connection when trying to create a new virtual machine.